# How to calculate summary of result in Total result from table row

Tags: angularjs

am able to calculate two inputs and saving result in result input and adding new row ,
but i want to calculate summary of result values in total Result(this input is outside of tr)

```
[here is my code][1]



 https://jsbin.com/gewigopevo/edit?html,js,output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the

```
$scope.Total = total
```

out of the `for loop` and place

```
$scope.rvm.push({})
```

at the end of the `addRow1` `function`

Your `function` should look like below

```
$scope.addRow1 = function (index) {
      $scope.rvm[index].result = $scope.rvm[index].val1 - $scope.rvm[index].val2;
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.rvm.length; i++) {
          total += parseInt($scope.rvm[i].result);

        }
      $scope.Total = total;
      $scope.rvm.push({});
    }
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/04885499/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at you code. I added a counter for total that aggregates the total after every add event occurs there calculating a running total. I pass this to a `$scope` variable outside of the table.

**In the controller**

```
    $scope.outsidetotal = 0; //outside of table scope
    $scope.rvm = [{}];
    var total = 0;
    $scope.total = 0;

  $scope.addRow1 = function (index) {
        $scope.rvm[index].result = $scope.rvm[index].val1 - $scope.rvm[index].val2;
        $scope.rvm.push({})
        $scope.outsidetotal = $scope.total += $scope.rvm[index].result;  
    }
```

**[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/yehawonude/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Answer (score 0):

try using watch

Add below lines in addRow1 function:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("rvm", function() {
    $scope.Total = total();
});
```

And then create a function total() and get the sum of all the result values.

```
function total() {
    var totalNumber = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.rvm.length; i++){
      totalNumber = totalNumber + parseInt($scope.rvm[i].result);
    }
    return totalNumber;
  }
```